# "My and my sister, Anna Smith's records" or "My and my sister's, Anna Smith, records."

Tags: possessives, grammatical-case, saxon-genitive, compound-possessives

I'm writing a request letter to my and my sister's high school but I don't how to properly say it.

**I, Rebecca Smith, would like to request a copy of my and my sister, Anna Smith's Transcript of Records.**

or

**I,Rebecca Smith, would like to request a copy of my and my sister's, Anna Smith, Transcript of Records.**

if both are wrong, please tell me a better sentence and also, if something is wrong in this question, you can correct it.
Thank you very much

Comment: There is no happy solution that involves an apostrophe. You have to reword. We have duplicates of this question.

Comment: My problem here is adding the name of the sister. If there is no name, I think "my and my sister's records" is correct. 
But if you put the name there, it sounds wrong to me. "my and my sister's, Anna Smith, records"

Comment: Yes, all those sound wrong. You need your transcripts and those of your sister.

Comment: "I, Rebecca Smith, would like to request a copy of my records and my sister, Anna Smith's records." seems fine but sounds repetitive, doesn't it?

Comment: You need your records and your sister's records. There simply is no good way to do this in English. Reword.

Comment: "I, Rebecca Smith, would like to request a copy of my records and those of my sister, Anna Smith."

Comment: If you write *"I, Rebecca Smith, would like to request a copy of my and my sister, Anna Smith's Transcript of Records"* as in question, there is a big risk that some stupid person will send you *only* Anna Smith's records. *"I, Rebecca Smith, would like to request a copy of my records and my sister, Anna Smith's records" seems fine but sounds repetitive, doesn't it?"* __ When you write to universities you must be extremely clear like that, even at risk of repetition. "A copy of my records and *also* my sister Anna Smith's records" would be a small improvement in the reading.